# Save search results

Tags: windows, search, active-directory

In the Directory Service Find dialog, I'm given the option to save my search, but not save the results.  How can I save the results of the search?

Would it be easier to copy the directory, if my search was designed to pick up all *items* in the directory?

(I'm not sure *items* was the right word, I mean to say Users, Groups, Printers...)

Comment: Why do you want to save the results? It seems to defeat the purpose of searching.

Comment: So I want the full names of everyone at my school.  The search listed every single user (about 8 thousand in the school district), and I'd like to make a copy of all those names.